# Match pattern within column

Tags: r

I want to match certain words and numbers and subset those rows from data frame.

```
match_words<-data.frame("words"=c("ING","HDFC","HSBC","ROYAL"))

df <- data.frame(bank_issue = c("ING,HDFC", "ROYAL,SINGB","GR01565B,HSBC","01565,BOC","BOA,JPG001","G001"))
```

When I try to match 1st word using `grep`, I am getting 2 rows which match& contains the word, but I need only those rows which match whole word. I need to subset that row from `df`.

I am using grep function. Here is what I am getting now:

```
grep("ING",df$bank_issue)
# [1] 1 2
```

And also i need to do for each row.

Desired Output:

```
1 ING    ING,HDFC
2 01565  01565,BOC
3 G001   G001
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the word boundary metacharacter.

```
grep("\\bING\\b",df$bank_issue)
#[1] 1
```

If you need to create these search patterns programmatically, you can use `paste0`.

```
terms <- paste0("\\b",unlist(match_words),"\\b")
sapply(terms,function(x){grep(x,df$bank_issue)})
#  \\bING\\b  \\bHDFC\\b  \\bHSBC\\b \\bROYAL\\b 
#          1           1           3           2
```